# How to handle SignalProducer with ReactiveSwift and Firebase asynchronous method calls?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, reactive-swift

I am working on an iOS App with Swift 3 using ReactiveSwift 1.1.1, the MVVM + Flow Coordinator pattern and Firebase as a backend. I only recently started to adapt to FRP and I am still trying to figure out how to integrate new functionalities into my existing code base.

For instance, my model uses a asynchronous method from Firebase to download thumbnails from the web and I want to provide a `SignalProducer<Content, NoError>` to subscribe from my ViewModel classes and observe, if thumbnails have been downloaded, which then updates the UI.

```
// field to be used from the view-models to observe
public let thumbnailContentSignalProducer = SignalProducer<Content, NoError> { (observer, disposable) in
    // TODO: send next content via completion below
} 

// thumbnail download method
public func findThumbnail(bucketId: String, contentId: String) {
    guard let userId = userService.getCurrentUserId() else {
        debugPring("Error id")
        return
    }

    let ref = self.storageThumbnail.reference()
    let contentRef = ref
        .child(userId)
        .child(bucketId)
        .child(FirebaseConstants.pathImages)
        .child("\(contentId).jpg")

    contentRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            debugPrint("Error download")
            return
        }
        let content = Image(data: data)
        content.id = contentId
        content.userId = userId
        content.bucketId = bucketId

        // TODO: emit signal with content
        // How to send the content via the SignalProducer above?
    })
}
```

I have also tried something similar with `Signal<Content, NoError>`, whereas I used the `Signal<Content, NoError>.pipe()` method to receive a `(observer, disposable)` tuple and I saved the observer as a private global field to access it form the Firebase callback.

**Questions:**

Is this the right approach or am I missing something?

How do I emit the content object on completion?

**UPDATE:**

After some hours of pain, I found out how to design the SingalProducer to emit signals and to subscribe from the ViewModels.

Maybe the following code snippet will help also others:

```
// model protocol
import ReactiveSwift
import enum Result.NoError

public protocol ContentService {
    func findThumbnail(bucketId: String, contentId: String)
    var thumbnailContentProducer: SignalProducer<Content, NoError> { get }
}


// model implementation using firebase
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import ReactiveSwift

public class FirebaseContentService: ContentService {

    // other fields, etc.
    // ...

    private var thumbnailContentObserver: Observer<Content, NoError>?
    private var thumbnailContentSignalProducer: SignalProducer<Content, NoError>?
    var thumbnailContentProducer: SignalProducer<Content, NoError> {
        return thumbnailContentSignalProducer!
    }

    init() {
        thumbnailContentSignalProducer = SignalProducer<Content, NoError> { (observer, disposable) in
            self.thumbnailContentObserver = observer
        }
    }

    func findThumbnail(bucketId: String, contentId: String) {
        guard let userId = userService.getCurrentUserId() else {
            // TODO handle error
            return
        }

        let ref = self.storageThumbnail.reference()
        let contentRef = ref
            .child(userId)
            .child(bucketId)
            .child(FirebaseConstants.pathImages)
            .child("\(contentId).jpg")

        contentRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                // TODO handle error
                return
            }
            let content = Image(data: data)
            content.id = contentId
            content.userId = userId
            content.bucketId = bucketId
            // emit signal
            self.thumbnailContentObserver?.send(value: content)
        })
    }
}


// usage from a ViewModel
contentService.thumbnailContentProducer
    .startWithValues { content in
        self.contents.append(content)
    }
```

Maybe someone can verify the code above and say that this is the right way to do it.

Comment: To clarify: you ultimately want to have one signal that can be observed which will send a value each time `findThumbnail` is called?

Comment: @jjoelson Yes, so far I found a own solution and edited the post above. Is the solution ok?

Comment: Your solution looks a bit fragile. The closure in `init` gets called each time a client calls `start`, meaning `thumbnailContentObserver` can get switched at any time, which means the `Content` values can be diverted to a different signal at any time. My solution ensures all `Content` values come on a single `Signal` which can be subscribed to multiple times if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right path when you were looking at using `Signal` with `pipe`. The key point is that you need to create a new `SignalProducer` for each thumbnail request, and you need a way to combine all of those requests into one resulting signal. I was thinking something like this (note this is untested code, but it should get the idea across):

```
class FirebaseContentService {
    // userService and storageThumbnail defined here
}

extension FirebaseContentService: ReactiveExtensionsProvider { }

extension Reactive where Base: FirebaseContentService {
    private func getThumbnailContentSignalProducer(bucketId: String, contentId: String) -> SignalProducer<Content, ContentError> {
        return SignalProducer<Content, ContentError> { (observer, disposable) in
            guard let userId = self.base.userService.getCurrentUserId() else {
                observer.send(error: ContentError.invalidUserLogin)
                return
            }

            let ref = self.base.storageThumbnail.reference()
            let contentRef = ref
                .child(userId)
                .child(bucketId)
                .child(FirebaseConstants.pathImages)
                .child("\(contentId).jpg")

                contentRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                guard let data = data else {
                    observer.send(error: ContentError.contentNotFound)
                    return
                }
                let content = Image(data: data)
                content.id = contentId
                content.userId = userId
                content.bucketId = bucketId

                observer.send(value: content)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            })
        }
    }
}

class ThumbnailProvider {
    public let thumbnailSignal: Signal<Content, NoError>

    private let input: Observer<(bucketId: String, contentId: String), NoError>

    init(contentService: FirebaseContentService) {
        let (signal, observer) = Signal<(bucketId: String, contentId: String), NoError>.pipe()

        self.input = observer
        self.thumbnailSignal = signal
            .flatMap(.merge) { param in
                return contentService.reactive.getThumbnailContentSignalProducer(bucketId: param.bucketId, contentId: param.contentId)
                    .flatMapError { error in
                        debugPrint("Error download")
                        return SignalProducer.empty
                    }
            }
    }

    public func findThumbnail(bucketId: String, contentId: String) {
        input.send(value: (bucketId: bucketId, contentId: contentId))
    }
}
```

Using `ReactiveExtensionsProvider` like this is the idiomatic way of adding reactive APIs to existing functionality via a `reactive` property.

The actual requesting code is confined to `getThumbnailContentSignalProducer` which creates a SignalProducer for each request. Note that errors are passed along here, and the handling and conversion to `NoError` happens later.

`findThumbnails` just takes a `bucketId` and `contentId` and sends it through the input observable.

The construction of `thumbnailSignal` in `init` is where the magic happens. Each input, which is a tuple containing a `bucketId` and `contentId`, is converted into a request via `flatMap`. Note that the `.merge` strategy means the thumbnails are sent as soon as possible in whatever order the requests complete. You can use `.concat` if you want to ensure that the thumbnails are returned in the same order they were requested.

The `flatMapError` is where the potential errors get handled. In this case it's just printing "Error download" and doing nothing else.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code above saved my day. I have made some minor corrections and updated my original post.

Comment: OK, I approved the edits, though I'm not sure why you want `thumbnailSignalRef` to be mutable and optional. It just needs to be set once in `init`, so imo it should be immutable and non-optional.

Comment: The problem is that I can't initialize the `thumbnailSignal` the way you described, because I receive a compile error due to the `self.getThumbnailContentSignalProducer`: Variable `self.thumbnailSignal` used before being initialized. I want to define a getter property in the protocol and define it via the implementing class in the init constructor, but I have tried bending that line all the way from weak to unowned etc. and can't define it better. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the best way to handle this is to separate out the code that provides the final `Signal` from the actual service code. Then you can pass the service class as a dependency. I will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: Super update!!! That was exactly, what I was looking for!!! Thank you for the great support @jjoelson. :) I would up-vote your answer, if I had a higher Stackoverflow rank.